# CakePHP - replace microsoft word character

Tags: cakephp

What would be the best way to replace microsoft word character in CakePHP?

So I'm trying to run the following function before edit or save etc on every text fields.

```
function convert_ms_chars($string) 
{ 
    $search = array(chr(145), 
                    chr(146), 
                    chr(147), 
                    chr(148), 
                    chr(151)); 

    $replace = array("'", 
                     "'", 
                     '"', 
                     '"', 
                     '-'); 

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string); 
}
```

The way I'm doing it now feels super ghetto.

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    $this->data['field'] = $this->convert_ms_chars($this->data['field']);
    $this->data['field1'] = $this->convert_ms_chars($this->data['field1']);
}
```

Not to mention that I need to copy this on several controllers.
Is there a better way I can approach this?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

**Code Organization** - if it is a library method (i.e something you are going to use across lots of controllers) you should think about placing it somewhere else (a commonly referenced file) instead of having the same code in multiple controllers.

**Functional Need** - as far as I know that's pretty much the way to do it.  You could condense it into one line, but ultimately you are replacing characters in a string; using the string replace method is how that gets done.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to slifty's comment, the best way to do this in CakePHP is to create a component which includes your `convert_ms_chars` method.

Then you just have to add that component to your `$components` array in each controller you would like to use it. Then you can call it by doing `$this->YourComponentName->convert_ms_chars()` where appropriate.

If you want to do this every time yo do a `save()` you can also add it to the Models `beforeSave()` callback. This way, CakePHP will automatically clean your data when you save the data of the Model.